# ng-model of `<select>` not selecting when model is an object

Tags: angularjs

### How to set ng model value to form fields? ng model value not reflecting on my form

I have a `$scope.obj`, this obj from server when i try to apply in my form like
`ng-model="obj.name"`, its not reflecting in `<select>` field. How to solve this issue?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="empEdit.qualification"
         ng-options="qualification as qualification.qualificationName
                     for qualification in qualifications"
         name="qualification"> 
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
    Choose your qualification
  </option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.empEdit = {
    "name":"SomeName",
    "id": 2,
    qualification: {"id":1,"qualification_name: "BS"}
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually it's not reflecting in <select></select> field

Comment: It's hard to help you with a bug in your code when the question does not include any of the buggy code. Read [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: use track by expression i.e. `qualifications track by qualification.id`

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-model` directive compares object *references* not object *contents*. Use a primitive property for the `ng-model` value:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="empEdit.qualById"
        ng-options="q.id as q.qualificationName for q in qualifications"
        name="selQual1"> 
  <option value="" disabled>
    Choose your qualification
  </option>
</select>
```

```
 $scope.empEdit = {"name":"SomeName", "id": 2, qualById: 1};
```

For more information, see

- [why does Javascript comparison not work with objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)
- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference - `select as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)